# Jquery Slider no longer works in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, slider

My Jquery slider as of now works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox and at one point worked perfectly in IE. But as i am finishing up the site, Its no longer working and i have no idea why. [Here](http://www.stonewallinsurancegroup.com) is a link to the site. And [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gbcbw/) is a link to the code as its too long to put here! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

    `.gotojsfiddle{
}`

Comment: Use Web Developer tool : There is an error...SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext' 
allinone_bannerWithPlaylist.js, line 9 character 15831

Comment: How would i go about fixing this? Thanks for the find

Answer (score 2):

if you changed the jquery plugin, maybe you will have some problems, cause some functions were removed on version 1.9.1 http://jquery.com/download/ there you will find the migrate plugin take a look it.

Comment: The plugin is created for 1.9.1 and worked fine with it before hand, it just abruptly stopped working. I did try what you suggested but no luck.